# Servelt Database Connectivity: JDBC, ODBC, Connection Pooling and

Tags: database, servlets, connection

For an exam question, I am looking at the various ways in which a servlet can make a connection to a database connection. So far I have

1. JDBC
2. ODBC
3. Database Pooling

But the question asks for 4, and I cannot seem to find the 4th alternative. Does it actually exist?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you might want to look at the Java Persistence API. Go Google JPA.

Answer (score 0):

I would add JNDI lookup and connecting directly using `DriverManager`. And what is *database pooling*? Do you mean *connection* pooling?

On the other hand if they are asking about high-level technologies: [jdbc](/questions/tagged/jdbc) -> [mybatis](/questions/tagged/mybatis) -> [hibernate](/questions/tagged/hibernate) -> [jpa](/questions/tagged/jpa).

Answer (score 0):

A servlet can't really use ODBC it might be able to use a JDBC via ODBC driver, but the servlet sees only ODBC.

Similarly Connection Pooling just pools JDBC connections. The connections are just made via JDBC.

Since the expected answer is 4 they might be asking for the [4 types of JDBC drivers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Database_Connectivity#Types)